# Sending login and form information from a webserver script (PHP), Cronjob?

Tags: php, cron, bots

I have friends who book rooms at a university, but can only book after midnight the next day when all the other students have booked. They don't want to stay up until midnight to book and wanted to know if a script could be written to send the login user details, encrypted on the webserver, and their usual day and time.The booking information is just a standard HTML form with relevant inputs. This data can be auto-generated from a list.

Is this possible to do from a webserver, or will they have to use their home machines and have a refresh at 00:01?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You could setup a cron-job and do a curl request. If it is just one page (logon and booking) it's easy, otherwise you would have to do two requests and make sure the session cookie gets stored.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Now go try writing some code.

Comment: Thank you @jeroen, I will read up on CURL.

Comment: @sammitch, I am middle-tier OO C++ developer, so this is not an area of expertise. I don't have clue about how to start these scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am middle-tier OO C++ developer

Well this should be dead-simple for you then. After you learn *one* language you should be able to pick up other, similar languages by reading some basic docs. [Here's the basic tutorial *from* the official doc.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php) Basically just stop worrying about memory allocation and static typing, read up on [how PHP does classes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php), and then [dig into cURL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) like jeroen mentioned.

Honestly, you're lucky this didn't get closed as 'not a real question' before I even got a chance to post a snippy comment. StackOverflow is very "code-oriented" and the questions that get the most attention are the ones where people post code that they've actually tried running along with a description of what's gone wrong and/or error info.

Your question, though better written than most, still comes across as, "I have tried/written nothing, someone please spoon-feed me some code". So go try some code and if you hit something you can't figure your way past, post that and I'll probably sound like less of a b-hole.

Comment: the tone of my reply was not meant to cause offence, it was requesting any pointers to the technical methods I should be looking into. 

I've been in I.T. over 20 years and the languages aren't a problem, it's the techniques to apply to meet the requirements. I've used PASACL, FORTRAN, CORAL, LISP, VB, C, C++, Documentum, MediaSurface, and all the rest of the internet interpreted languages.

Comment: But sometimes you come up against requests to write a TCPIP package to an SMS message to transmit over an x25 protocol network, which isn't a question of language, but method.

I search SO as a resource for references not just for code snippets, it can help in both ways.

Thank you again for the references, and I will close this thread.

Barton.